# 45 Degree Angle Python Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

In tkinter, python, I'm currently trying to make an output of so when a button is clicked, an angled line (pointing in a 45 degree direction) is put onto the canvas. Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x900")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, height=820)
canvas.pack()
png = PhotoImage(file = r'C:\Users\--\Desktop\Programming\GP\europe1.gif') #Map of europe
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = png, anchor = "nw")
london = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, 10, 5, fill='red')
londontext = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text="London") #Creating labelled cities for europe picture
paris = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, 10, 5, fill='red')
paristext = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text="Paris")
canvas.move(london, 226, 390)
canvas.move(londontext, 210, 374)
canvas.move(paristext, 230, 447) # Sets correct coords for the two cities
canvas.move(paris, 247, 462)
def gotoparis():
    parisline = canvas.create_line(100, 0, 100, 100, 45) 
def gotolondon():                 # Trying to make a line form between the two cities
    londonline = canvas.create_line(100, 0, 100, 100, 45) 
def londonclick(event):
    londoninterface = Tk()
    londoninterface.geometry("400x400")
    ll = Label(londoninterface, text="London Airport")
    ll.pack()
    blank = Label(londoninterface, text="")    # Creating new windows
    blank.pack()
    l1 = Label(londoninterface, text="Send Flight To:")
    l1.pack()
    toparis = Button(londoninterface, text="Paris", command=gotoparis)
    toparis.pack()
def parisclick(event):
    parisinterface = Tk()
    parisinterface.geometry("400x400")
    ll = Label(parisinterface, text="Paris Airport")
    ll.pack()
    blank = Label(parisinterface, text="")
    blank.pack()
    l1 = Label(parisinterface, text="Send Flight To:")
    l1.pack()
    tolondon = Button(parisinterface, text="London")
    tolondon.pack()

canvas.tag_bind(london, '<ButtonPress-1>', londonclick)    # Makes it so when rectangle is clicked, a new window pops up
canvas.tag_bind(paris, '<ButtonPress-1>', parisclick)
```

As you can probably tell, I'm trying to make an airport like game where you can set a plane to a destination, and with that it creates a line of where it is going to end up. This code is a bit hard to understand what I am trying to do, but in short, I want to create a line between two canvas created rectangles when a tkinter button is clicked. Just to clarify, I'm using python 3.5.2 tkinter.
Also, this code doesn't create an error message or any type of error but it doesn't do what I want it to do. That basically sums it up.

Comment: I get an error message when I click the `Paris` button after clicking on the London point: `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # coordinates: expected an even number, got 5` because you give 5 coordinates in `canvas.create_line(100, 0, 100, 100, 45) ` instead of an even number.

Comment: the 45 is meant to be the angle size e.g. 45° angle

Comment: I don't see a question in your question. What do you need help with? All you've done is tell us what you want to do, but haven't explained the problem you're having.

Comment: Did you read some documentation somewhere that says the `create_line` method takes an angle as an argument? It doesn't.

Comment: I want to try and make it so when a button is clicked, a line between two points is created, but I do not know how.

Comment: The first step when you don't know how to do something is to read the documentation.  You shouldn't just start throwing parameters in a command and hope that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax for creating a line on a canvas:

`Canvas.create_line(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ..., x_n, y_n, **kwargs)`

(x_i, y_i) are the points that will be linked by the line and the kwargs set the style of the line (fill, width,... see [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_line.html) for an exhaustive list). So you cannot give a 45° angle as argument.

I used the coordinates of the center of each square to draw the line between them. The initial center of a city is in (7.5, 2.5), then it is moved by (x_city, y_city):

```
london = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, 10, 5, fill='red')
londontext = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text="London") #Creating labelled cities for europe picture
paris = canvas.create_rectangle(5, 0, 10, 5, fill='red')
paristext = canvas.create_text(10, 10, text="Paris")

# Sets correct coords for the two cities
x_london, y_london = 226, 390
canvas.move(london, x_london, y_london)
canvas.move(londontext, 210, 374)
x_paris, y_paris = 247, 462
canvas.move(paris, x_paris, y_paris)
canvas.move(paristext, 230, 447) 

def gotoparis():
    parisline = canvas.create_line(x_london + 7.5, y_london + 2.5, 
                                   x_paris + 7.5, y_paris + 2.5) 
def gotolondon():                
    londonline = canvas.create_line(x_london + 7.5, y_london + 2.5, 
                                    x_paris + 7.5, y_paris + 2.5)
```

Comment: When the Go To London button is pressed nothing happens. - EDIT: I made a mistake with the button command, this does work, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `line` item of tkinter canvas does not support the "angle" option that the `text` item does, but you can rotate a `line` (or a `polygon`) by:
(1) calculating the new coordinates of a rotated item, and
(2) updating the item's coordinates with the `coords()` method.
If you know the start and end points of the desired line, you can pass them into the `create_line()` method and you'll get the line you want angled the way you want it right up front.

Rotating a line is simple when it only consists of a single line segment / two points, as in coords=(x1, y1, x2, y2). But be aware that you can add additional points/coordinates to make a more complicated line.